# Input form wont submit?

Tags: php, forms, submit

```
protected function pro_show_sendRequestForm(){
    echo("<SECTION id='page_content-small'>");
    echo("<ARTICLE>");
    echo("<table width='100%' cellspacing='5'>");
    echo("<tr><td><form method='post' action='main.php'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td colspan ='2' align='center'><B><H2>Send a event form.</H2></B></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td align='left'><B>Name event:</B></td>");
    echo("<td align='left'><input name='sEventTitle' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50' required></td></tr>");   
    echo("<tr><td align='left'><B>Name organisation:</B></td>");          
    echo("<td align='left'><B>New: </B><input name='sNewOrganisationName' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='left'><B>Or choose: </B>");
    $this->pro_OrganisationDropdown('sExcistingOrganisationRecordNumber'); 
    echo("</td><tr>");
    echo("<tr><td align='left'><B>E-mail address:</B></td><td align='left'>"); 
    echo("<input name='sEmailadress' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50' required></td></tr>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='sSubmitForm' value='SendIntakeForm'>");
    echo("<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'><input type='submit' value=' Sending '></td></tr>");
    echo("</form></table></ARTICLE></SECTION>");
}
```

Hi you all,
Today I created this form and it worked fine. Until I started with testing and then i discovered that a certain value in the input field 'sEventTitle' was the reason that the form wasn't processed. I checked and rechecked but the value for example 'Apple' was excepted and the value 'pineapple' wasn't.
So to discover why, I commented all other input fields out like this:

```
protected function pro_show_sendRequestForm(){
    echo("<SECTION id='page_content-small'>");
    echo("<ARTICLE>");
    echo("<table width='100%' cellspacing='5'>");
    echo("<tr><td><form method='post' action='main.php'></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td colspan ='2' align='center'><B><H2>Send a event form.</H2></B></td></tr>");
    echo("<tr><td align='left'><B>Name event:</B></td>");
    echo("<td align='left'><input name='sEventTitle' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50' required></td></tr>");   
    //echo("<tr><td align='left'><B>Name organisation:</B></td>");          
    //echo("<td align='left'><B>New: </B><input name='sNewOrganisationName' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50'></td></tr>");
    //echo("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align='left'><B>Or choose: </B>");
    //$this->pro_OrganisationDropdown('sExcistingOrganisationRecordNumber'); 
    //echo("</td><tr>");
    //echo("<tr><td align='left'><B>E-mail address:</B></td><td align='left'>"); 
    //echo("<input name='sEmailadress' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50' required></td></tr>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='sSubmitForm' value='SendIntakeForm'>");
    echo("<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'><input type='submit' value=' Sending '></td></tr>");
    echo("</form></table></ARTICLE></SECTION>");
}
```

Now the entire form wont submit itself. This can not be true.
The basics are there: form and /form. A input name ='foo' type='text' and a submit button.  Why is this form not submitted when the larger one is working?  What is my mistake? Is there something I don't see? Any help is appriciated.

The first lines from main.php to see if the form is submitted are:

```
$oMainPage = new main();
echo($_POST['sEventTitle']);
echo($_POST['sSubmitForm']);
```

The code generated from the browser:

```
 <SECTION id='page_content-small'><ARTICLE><form method='post' action='main.php'>
 <table width='100%' cellspacing='5'><tr><td colspan ='2' align='center'><B>  
 <H2>Een aanmeldformulier versturen.</H2></B></td></tr><tr><td align='left'>  
 <B>Naam evenement:</B></td><td align='left'>  
 <input name='sEventTitle' type='text' size='30' maxlength='50' required></td></tr>  
 <input type='hidden' name='sSubmitForm' value='SendIntakeForm'><tr>  
 <td colspan='3' align='center'><input type='submit' value=' Versturen '></td></tr>  
 </table></form></ARTICLE></SECTION>
```

Comment: Please do not use echo for every single row. Keep your php and template (html) separated.

Comment: @hardy. I know, but this is code in errormode, so i can find where the error could be.

Comment: I have no problem with your code. [Test it here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/iKhYj2)

Comment: @cyper. youre rigth the code is solid, thats why its so strange. It should work but it doesn't. And I cant find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

take the form out of the `<td>`, wrap the `<form>` around that `<table>`

Comment: Good eye T McKeown, I missed that in jdkos post.

Comment: I did as you suggested and wrapped the the form around the table. But still no joy.

Comment: paste your html, do a "view source" from the browser.  paste what is being generated.

Comment: I pasted the code, but i can't see anything wrong it. Do you?

Comment: what is `<Section><Article>`??

Comment: those aren't valid elements, that is probably what is cause your form element from working.

Comment: Those are the new tags within HTML 5.